# How to disable highlighting for custom group

Tags: highlight

I'm using a tip from [this page of the vim wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) to highlight trailing spaces when I'm not in insert mode :

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

Now, I would like to disable this highlighting (just like all the other ones) with `:syntax off`. It turns out that it disables my colorscheme, but not this specific highlight group.

I've tried to add those lines to my colorscheme file, instead of my `.vimrc`, but it doesn't work either. The `ExtraWhitespace` group is always highlighted, even with `:syntax off`. How can I disable it ?

---

I think there's a bug in vim/Neovim here.

I assume that the answer to my question would be the following one (suggested by D. Ben Knoble, thank you!):

```
function! TrailingSpaces()
   if exists("syntax_on")
      match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
   else
      match NONE
   endif
endfunction
autocmd Syntax * call s:TrailingSpaces()
```

The `highlight` command should then be put in the theme file.

Or the following one should work too with the original code:

```
autocmd Syntax * if exists("syntax_on") | hi ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red | else | hi clear ExtraWhitespace | endif
```

But in fact, none of them is working. It seems that the `syntax` event is never triggered.

The following code *should* do something, right?

```
function! Test()
   echo "This is a test."
endfunction
autocmd Syntax * call Test()
```

But nothing ever happens when I set `:syntax off` or `:syntax on`.

Tested with a clean vimrc, both with vim and Neovim (latest versions from the Arch Linux repos).

Am I missing something here? Could anyone confirm this?

Comment: `match` and `syntax` use different mechanisms. You can `hi clear ExtraWhitespace` I think

Comment: You're right ! `hi clear ExtraWhitespace` disables it manually... Is there a way to do it each time "syntax off" is set ? I've tried `autocmd ColorScheme * hi clear ExtraWhitespace` both in my `.vimrc` and my colorscheme files, but it has no effect at all... Thanx for your help !

Comment: there's an event for syntax you could try

Comment: I can't figure it out. I tried this in my theme file : `autocmd Syntax * if exists("syntax_on") | hi ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red | else | hi clear ExtraWhitespace | endif` but it still has no effect... What am I doing wrong ?